# Queue method problem white problem is it will delete the data?

Tags: java, queue

When i add this in the program,it has a problem.

```
while (true) {
    boolean h1Status = false, h2Status = false, h3Status = false;

    if (h1.isEmpty() == false) {
        if (h1.last() == LastBuffer + 1) {

            LastBuffer++;
            System.out.println("Move parcel " + LastBuffer + " from input buffer to output buffer directly");
            h1Status = true;
        }

    } else if (h2.isEmpty() == false) {
        if (h2.last() == LastBuffer + 1) {
            LastBuffer++;
            System.out.println("Move parcel " + LastBuffer + " from input buffer to output buffer directly");

            h2Status = true;
        }

    } else if (h3.isEmpty() == false) {
        if (h3.last() == LastBuffer + 1) {

            LastBuffer++;
            System.out.println("Move parcel " + LastBuffer + " from input buffer to output buffer directly");
            h3Status = true;
        }
    } else if (h1Status == false && h2Status == false && h3Status == false) {
        break;
    }
}
```

and the error

```
Exception in thread "main" EmptyListException: List is empty.
    at LinkedList.removeFromTail(LinkedList.java:54)
    at LinkedQueue.HeadCheck(LinkedQueue.java:56)
    at ParcelQueues.main(ParcelQueues.java:124)
```

I added two of the method in queue

```
public int last()
{   
    Object item=qll.removeFromHead();

    int i=(int)item;
    return i;

}
```

another:

```
public int HeadCheck()
{   
    Object item=qll.removeFromTail();

    int i=(int)item;
    qll.addToTail(item);
    return i;

}
```

how can I solve the problem?I solved it around 3 hours.It like a Parcel arrangement for delivery.When 1 output to the buffer.It needs to check all of the queue(h1,h2,h3)to the buffer.The Finally output is (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

Comment: Could you please explain what this program is supposed to be doing? Please explain it in text.

Comment: Like if i enter(5,8,1,7,4,2,9,6,3).The program will put all of the data in 3 queue.If there is a 1 in the data,it will put in the buffer.And the final output is(1,2,3)

Comment: I must be dense, but I still don't understand why this is being done. Yes, I understand it is homework. You could put in the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: if i input(3,6,9,2,4,7,1,8,5) and th output is(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

Comment: You're trying to sort the array? But there seems to be something else involving a buffer?

Comment: ys I am trying to sort the array but I can't solve the EmptyListException problem.

Comment: You really need to include more code here. Any code here should be a Minimal Reproducible Example. That it, it should be highlight the problem without having extra code, and it should be capable to being compiled all on its own.